# How to fix read-the-docs build failure on an old release

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I have a project on GitHub with a single master branch and multiple tagged releases.  The documentation is hosted on Read The Docs.  Six months ago I released version 0.7.0 and the documentation was built successfully.  After releasing version 0.8.0 today I realized it would be a good idea to publicly expose the docs for the old 0.7.0 release for users who are not ready to upgrade.  However, when I tried to build the old docs from the admin page, they don't compile anymore.  The old conf.py contains the mathjax sphinx extension, which results in a build failure.  What is the right way to build docs for a release that is 6 months old?

Comment: Do you want to maintain multiple release versions? We do that for Pyramid, one branch per version. As far as build failures, you need to provide more information. Links to your build's error log and public repo of docs source files would be a good start.

Comment: @Steve Piercy, How does RTD know it should generate docs for the Pyramid release branches?  It looks like Pyramid has both tagged releases and release branches.  It's unclear where RTD will look for the documentation files associated with each release.

Comment: RTD will scan your repo for branches and you can use those as versions. See how this https://readthedocs.org/projects/pyramid/versions/ maps to this https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/branches/all. Then in your project's RTD `Admin > Versions`, you can make specific branches to be "active".

Comment: Oh, and it is not documented well, if at all, on RTD. :(